# IP doesn't change to the domain name

Tags: web-hosting, web-development

I am facing this problem for quite a long time. When I enter the IP address of my website it take me to the website but the IP address doesn't change to the Domain Name. I am hosting my website on a Virtual Machine on Google Cloud. I am using the Google Cloud service as a hosting service for my website. Can someone help me in solving this problem?